# How do I disable notifications for a second Gmail account?

Tags: notifications, gmail

I have two Gmail accounts, one that I use for mailing lists and signing up for online services and whatnot, and the other one for more important stuff like work and friends.

I'd like to set it up so that my phone doesn't play the notification sound when an email comes in for the mailing list account. I only want to hear notifications for the account that has the more important email.

I can't find any setting to differentiate notifications between the two accounts.

Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: What version of Android? That might make a difference. Also, are you using the Gmail app or getting your Gmail messages with a different email app?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is what I did in Android 4.1 and Gmail:

1. Open Gmail
2. Tap the Overflow menu (three vertical dots) and select **Settings**
3. Tap the account for which you *don't* want to get notifications
4. Uncheck the **Notifications** option

That should be all you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

An Update for Android 12 or 13 Beta. Both versions were tested and confirmed.

1. Open Gmail App on your Android phone.

[image]

2. Choose the account to view.
3. At the top left there are 3 lines, tap the 3 lines.

[image]

4. Scroll down to Settings and tap Settings.

[image]

5. Choose the email you want to change.
6. Tap Notifications.

[image]

7. You have a choice of All, High Priority only, or None.

[image]

Once you make your choice, you're done and can back out of settings.