# Disable all notifications from one of multiple (two) Google accounts on my phone

Tags: notifications, google-account, accounts

I have two Google accounts on my phone; one for work and the other is my main personal account. I want to disable *all notifications* from my work account; that includes email *and calendar* and anything else. I've read [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39343/how-do-i-disable-notifications-for-a-second-gmail-account), by which I can disable *email* notifications, but all my *calendar notification* still show up. My question is, is it possible to disable *all notifications*, including email *and calendar*, from my work account on my phone?

By the way I'm on Android 14 and Pixel 8.

Comment: [That's how Google calendar is designed](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/250779/131553), so going by that answer you can't